# How to avoid duplicated content in bootstrap?

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

In my website I would like to display the phone number, and I would like to let the phone number be clickable when it is being accessed by the mobile website.

The following is the snippet of the code:

```js
class MyGrid extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { phone: "123" };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="d-block d-sm-none">
          <a href={"tel:" + this.state.phone}>
            <p className="footer-subheading text-link">{this.state.phone}</p>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div className="d-none d-sm-block">
          <p className="footer-subheading">{this.state.phone}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <MyGrid />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="react"></div>
```

The first part would be displayed on phone (the phone number is clickable) and the second part shows on tablet and up (only text). Although there is only one phone number is displayed, the search engine would warn me for having duplicated phone number. I would like to see if it can be solved in different way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I dont find any problem in that but if you want to avoid it, you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-responsive package

Comment: Thanks I guess that would work. I just wonder if there are some bootstrap / react-bootstrap magic that would make things more integrated (so I don't need to check the definition of xs/md and then manually type it on react-responsive).

Comment: @NishargShah from the user it would not be a problem at all, the problem only arise when I search engine warns me since the phone number is shown twice. Therefore I think I need to do this on the JS side so that it won't have duplicated content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`react-responsive`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-responsive) avoids the duplicated content is being rendered twice on the client. Here is the code snippet from the `react-responsive`:

```
import React from 'react'
import { useMediaQuery } from 'react-responsive' 

const Example = () => {
  const isDesktopOrLaptop = useMediaQuery({
    query: '(min-device-width: 1224px)'
  })
  const isBigScreen = useMediaQuery({ query: '(min-device-width: 1824px)' })
  const isTabletOrMobile = useMediaQuery({ query: '(max-width: 1224px)' })
  const isTabletOrMobileDevice = useMediaQuery({
    query: '(max-device-width: 1224px)'
  })
  const isPortrait = useMediaQuery({ query: '(orientation: portrait)' })
  const isRetina = useMediaQuery({ query: '(min-resolution: 2dppx)' })
 
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Device Test!</h1>
      {isDesktopOrLaptop && <>
        <p>You are a desktop or laptop</p>
        {isBigScreen && <p>You also have a huge screen</p>}
        {isTabletOrMobile && <p>You are sized like a tablet or mobile phone though</p>}
      </>}
      {isTabletOrMobileDevice && <p>You are a tablet or mobile phone</p>}
      <p>Your are in {isPortrait ? 'portrait' : 'landscape'} orientation</p>
      {isRetina && <p>You are retina</p>}
    </div>
  )
}
```

The original `bootstrap` way would show the content based on the screen size. But using `react-responsive` way would generate the content based on the screen size. Therefore the search engine would only get one copy of the content, based on it's screen size.